# Rails - custom patch action is redirected to update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To export csv file in Rails 4.2 app, a patch action `export_file` is added to routes.rb:

```
resources :payment_requests do
    collection do
      patch :export_file  
    end
end
```

In index view, a `form_tag` is added for csv:

```
   <%= form_tag export_file_payment_requests_path(format: 'csv'), method: :put do %>
      <%= submit_tag 'CSV' %>
    <% end %>
```

In `rake routes` output, there is path for `export_file`:

```
  export_file_payment_requests PATCH  /payment_requests/export_file(.:format)       payment_requestx/payment_requests#export_file
                               PATCH  /payment_requests/:id(.:format)               payment_requestx/payment_requests#update
                               PUT    /payment_requests/:id(.:format)               payment_requestx/payment_requests#update
```

However, when exporting csv, the action is `update` instead of `export_file` and it causes error in following exporting. What causes wrong routing to `update` for `patch` action `export_file`?

If `export_file` is declared as `get`, then the routing is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `method: :patch` on your form. Or change the method on routes to `put :export_file`. However I think the best choice in this case is use `get`.

Comment: put changed to patch in rails 4.

Comment: `<%= form_tag export_file_payment_requests_path(format: 'csv'), method: :patch do %>` works. Thought put and patch were the same for method:

Comment: rails is using `patch` instead of `put` on resourceful routing to update resources. you're creating a new non-resourceful route here. then you need choose the best http method to resolve your problem. it's not about "put changed to patch in rails 4.2". it'a about use the correct http method among all of them.